# Mysqli->multi_query doesn't exceute second query after once

Tags: php, sql

am really confuse about how this function works.
My aim is to insert data in 2 tables whenever users submit the form data.
1) whenever a user refresh, data is suppose to be inserted sequentially in the two table, but in this case only table image below is affected.
http://prestadsng.com/capturedb2.png
2) If i try to submit another data apart from refreshing i get error, but the data is still added to the table (Error = Strict standards: mysqli::next_result(): There is no next result set. Please, call mysqli_more_results()/mysqli::more_results() to check whether to call this function/method in C:\wamp\www\pms\include\config.php on line 38)
3) the new inserted data id doesn't increment with ++ rather does this with image below
http://prestadsng.com/capturedb.png

What i actually want to achieve is
1) When a refresh is done data should be inserted on the two table
2) 2 query table shouldn't throw error, and also should with ++

My code are below

```
public function multiQueryInsert($query){
    if($this->conn->multi_query($query)){
        do{
            $this->conn->store_result();
            $this->conn->more_results();

        }
        while($this->conn->next_result());
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return $this->conn->errno;
    }
    $this->conn->close();
}

$query = "INSERT INTO `tbl1`(`name`, `phone`, `address`, `email`, `cell`, `pcf`, `church`, `subgroup`, `group`, `zone`, `dob`, `occupation`, `status`) VALUES ('$names','$phone','$address','$email','$cell','$pcf','$church','$subgroup','$group','$zone','$dob','$occupation','$status');";

$query .= "INSERT INTO `cec_users` (`uid`, `pswd`, `Name`, `Email`, `church`) VALUES ('$fname','$password','$names','$email','$church')";
        if($db->multiQueryInsert($query) === TRUE){
            echo '<div class="success"><p>Partner added successfully</p></div>';
        }
        else{
            echo '<div class="error"><p>Error adding partner: '.$db->conn->error.'</p></div>';
        }
```

Comment: `INSERT` queries don't have any results to store.

Comment: I've seen lots of questions with problems using `multi_query`. I don't see the point -- what does it gain over just calling `mysqli_query` multiple times?

Comment: @Barmar the second query doesn't get inserted to the table. i have remove the do{}while()

Comment: Looking at the data it appears as if the second table may have a primary or unique key constraint which is prevent duplicate records from being added.

Comment: @Verma You are right, i notice that and i have resolve it. Thank you.